# Gurobi quicksum syntax in c++

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, c++17, gurobi

I need the Syntax to create a sum in a Gurobi-constraint in c++:

EXAMPLE:
I have the variables:
*x[i][j]*

and the constraint:
*sum over all i's from x[i][j] <= 1       for all j's*

in **Gurobi Python** it is:
*for i in [list of i's]:
model.addConstr(x[i,j] <= 0 for j in [list of j's])*

How is the Syntax for this in **c++**?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
David Franck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, for example by including a [mcve] of *your own* attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: And finally a tip about your problem in doing translations: Don't! Don't try to translate a solution in one programming language directly into another. Instead start *fresh* and try to write  brand new implementation of the generic algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out:

```
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
     {
         GRBLinExpr expr = 0;
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            expr += vars[i][j];
         model.addConstr(expr <= 1, [name of constrain]);
     }
```